# SSRS and UAC problem

Tags: security, ssrs-2008

I have using SSRS 2008r2 on Windows2003 server and added Domain Users  group as a System Administrator via report manager. However, when I mimic an ordinary user in report manager web interface on my computer(member of the domain) I get;

User 'usera' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

if I try with user a on the server by using FQDN, it it shows same error above.

If I type localhost instead, it does work. while using localhost, it I navigate to a folder and while I am in a folder and change the localhost to FQDN, it still works.

There are lots of solutions on the web, like the one on http://skamie.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/ssrs-and-uac/, but it did not work..

Does  anyone have any idea?

Many Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried right-clicking on IE and select Run as Administrator?

I have to do that from time to time on my development machine so it is sort of first solution that came to mind. Hope it helps.

**Additional answer:**

So the Domain Users group has System Admin role. You can try adding that group as Browser role or Content Manager role at the root folder.